# Initialization using org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener entry in web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, log4j

In most of the Java projects using Spring, I find this entry in web.xml which is executed at server start-up:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

What is the purpose of `Log4jConfigListener`?

In my legacy project I can also see this setting. However when i dive into the code I do not find anything special done in this class or further classes called internally by this class. I am sure there must be some good purpose behind putting above code snippet and I am missing it.

In every class which putting the logs in file here is the entry

```
private static final Log    log  = LogFactory.getLog(PoolManagerImpl.class);
log.debug("Number of connection pools to create = ["
    + connection.size() + "]");
```

Even if I comment out my web.xml entry, logging works fine. So what is it's purpose?

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html

Comment: Bnjmn. Actually my question is my application works do the logging fine even without this listener entry?

Comment: It says Bootstrap listener for custom log4j initialization in a web environment.What custom initialization  it is doing and can do?

Comment: It configures spring to listen for external log4j configuration file at the root of your spring project. If you have a log4j.xml configured in the root, then the log manager will use the settings as specified there. Instead, the spring logger runs in the absence of that file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Log4jConfigListener` initialises the Log4j "subsystem" as soon the webapplication starts up, as opposed to "lazily configuring" it as soon as it is needed.

In my opinion, the main advantage of explicitly initializing log4j via the Log4JConfigListener is that it allows you to configure the location of the log4j configuration file through using servlet context parameters; depending on how the application is deployed, this may make it possible for the configuration to be changed at runtime by some kind of admin user without having to dig around inside the exploded WAR directory .

See the javadoc for [Log4jConfigListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html), and more importantly [Log4jWebConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jWebConfigurer.html), as it does the real work.

Comment: Charles Anthony . Do you have any idea what kind of initialization is done in  the Log4j "subsystem by Log4jConfigListener?Any high level idea?

Comment: @MSach Well, the javadoc linked to explains at some level - but, essentially, it says "Configure log4j from file X" where X is either extracted from web.xml, or defaulted. It also allows you to "watch" a configuration file, and if you do so, how often to check for changes.